# Is there an Android app that can allow me to edit Python files on my server?

Tags: android, python, ssh, bash, centos

I am looking for a way to edit python files on my server and run them. I have an SSH client on my android (SFTP costs a lot of money), but it is more for accessing the server rather than running scripts seriously. Typically, on my computer, I will use pyCharm that is connected to my server directly, so I can focus more on coding. Is there any lightweight Android text editor ( I figure an IDE would be too slow) that can connect directly to `.py` files on my server and run them through the server? Bonus points if it autocompletes. I am looking to create a Django website, and run data analysis programs if that helps at all. Also, I have a Samsung J3 although I hope to upgrade soon.

Comment: https://techwiser.com/android-text-editor-for-programming/

Comment: Have you tried https://jupyter.org/ or other notebook-style IDE's?  https://medium.com/@eleroy/using-django-in-jupyter-notebook-5f09073878bb shows it can work with Django.

Comment: Have you thought remote access?  Something like TightVNC? That would allow you to remotely access your server & run PyCharm there – if speed allows; if not, it would allow you to use PyCharm locally & then transfer the files. Typically, I will develop & debug my Python scripts on `localhost` before deploying them to the server, so it’s not too much trouble to just transfer files at the end of the development cycle.